Was the purported 1968 standard for encoding ASCII on punched cards ever used?
A 1968 Communications of the ACM article describes a proposed USA standard for encoding US ASCII (with a provision to encode all 256 bytes) on punched cards, attempting to keep existing industry standard encodings for capital letters, digits, and common punctuation.
The way control codes are assigned looks surprisingly haphazard. Unlike EBCDIC, it is impossible to tell how specific bytes with the high bit equal to 1 were intended to be punched, for example, where would 0x80 go, or 0xFF?
That said, were there any systems which actually used that encoding on punched cards, or its subset that is specific enough to ascertain its use?


That table uses a extreme unusual and unintuitive ordering. At first sight all encodings seem to be the same as used by EBCDIC. Might have to find time to read the cited article.

@Raffzahn The encoding for NUL is unexplainable. I would have expected it to be 12-11-0 or 12-11-0-9; and the other one for 0x80.

Huh? 12-11-0 and, 12-11-0-9 are forbidden combinations. A basic rule about punch card codes is to avoid adjacent holes - especially three or more - and never have the upper three (12-11-10). Nicely visible in above chart by having the 12-11-10 columns empty. (And yes, above table adds 9-8-7 combinations, but NUL is older - and those triplets are in the numeric area).

@Raffzahn Please read the description of the table. There are 256 hole-patterns for 256 8-bit codes. It means that all empty positions in the table are intended to be used.

Haven't denied that. Please also read my comment in whole. Punching for NUL was already defined by IBM BEFORE above table was proposed, following the no 12-11-10 rule. NUL is in wide use with IBM Systems, so any table designed for compatibility is not free to move it.

@Raffzahn I see. My misunderstanding stems from "12-11-0 and, 12-11-0-9 are forbidden combinations", which should have been "12-11-0 and, 12-11-0-9 previously were forbidden combinations".  Still, it remains unclear how the codes 0x80-0xFF are supposed to be assigned to hole-patterns.

My bad. I'm an old time mainframe guy, so to me those are customer side 'extensions' are just that: Not part of any standard. While ASCII was basic for remote I/O on mainframes, it never had any practical relation to punch cards and not at all for binary. After all, punch cards were always character based, not binary.

Having read the linked paper and thinking about it it seems as if the 'high bit set' part is not fleshed out at all. Only the basic 128 codes are assigned - which is what ASCII was back then and for the next 20 years - leaving the rest as suggested encoding space.

@Raffzahn some old computers (at least the 7094 -- and ancestors?) used punch cards for object decks.  The compile phase would produce a stack of object cards, and the operator would stack up numerous programs together (separated by some kind of JCL) to load them into the computer.  My understanding is that it was common to actually spool from card reader to tape, and each run would be loaded from the tape.

@MarkHarrison Not just ancestors, but descendants. Binary cards were commonly used on the IBM 1130 (late 60s-early 70s), both for code and data. See pages 59-62 of http://media.ibm1130.org/1130-055-ocr.pdf. Bottom-level encoding was straight binary, three 16 bit words every four columns. The "lace card" angst was not present in that corner of the culture.

@JohnDoty Note that there' a huge difference between readers/sorters used for card work that reached up to 2000+ CPM with transport distance of several meters and those small 200..800 CPS readers (no sorting output) used with common non card processing applications and job loading that moved a card just a few inches. Being that slow and non demanding their users weren't plagued as much-if at all. (also, even /390 and Z-Series can still read binary cards :))

@Raffzahn Did anyone using such high speed equipment even care about ASCII or any other shortened code?

@JohnDoty Users maybe not. Standard people rather yes. In any case the use of all 256 codes seems to me more about a theoretical exensinon - after all, ASCII was only defined as 7 bit - and still ist.

Multics came close. Multics used ASCII for its usual text representation, and could punch and read it from cards. There were only six differences between the Multics card code and the ANSI standard. From the linked document:


Be sort of interesting to know why there were any differences at all?  Why didn't the ASCII standards people just adopt the Multics encoding.  Nothing stands out from that table above to indicate why the right column is preferred over the left column ... and the left column was already in use, but there must have been a reason ...

@davidbak "Nothing", really? Counting the number of punches comes to mind.

Why is fewer punches for open/close bracket and vertical line a change worth making?  And it doesn't explain the other changes.  (FWIW, if I had to pay for card punching I was paying by the card, not by the number of holes in the cards ...)

@davidbak Perhaps, hole-pattern similarities of [ backslash ] mimic their closeness in the ASCII table; similarly for { | }.
The question to ask would be, what informed the Multics Standard Card Code, if its designers also wanted to encode ASCII.

This card code is not just proposed, it was actually adopted as a standard in ANSI X3.26-1970 Hollerith Punched Card Code (FIPS PUB 14), and remains in the most recent revision, ANSI X3.26-1980 Hollerith Punched Card Code FIPS PUB 14-1, May 1980.
The standard also includes extended punched-card codes for non-ASCII characters that would occupy byte values 128 through 255 decimal (0x80 through 0xff hexadecimal). I haven't found any specific evidence of vendors using these code definitions. It should be noted that the mapping of EBCDIC to punched card codes did ultimately include 256 codes, so it's possible that there is a full correspondence between them, though the non-card equivalents in ASCII and EBCDIC are obviously different.
However, the X3.26 punched card code for ASCII is not just some standard that was adopted but went unused. DEC used this exact card code in their card processing, at least as early as 1972. It is listed in the DECsystem 10 Operating System Commands manual, order number DEC-10-MRDC-C, 3rd printing, June 1972, in Appendix B, Card Codes, which is also reprinted as chapter 8 of the DECsystem 10 User's Handbook, second edition, 1972.
For DEC, this represented a change compared to their earlier practice, as documented in the (PDP-10 System Reference Manual, DEC-10-HGAA-D, April 1968, a slightly more recent version of which was reprinted in the 1970 PDP-10 Reference Handbook. These include, in Appendix B, Input-Output Codes, a table of card codes, whcih includes "DEC 029" and "DEC 026" codes. These cover the the DEC "SIXBIT" subset of ASCII 1963 (ASA X3.4-1963), which only includes the characters in columns 2 through 5 (hexadecimal codes 0x20 through 0x5f), no controls, no lower case. The DEC 029 code is quite similar to, but not quite identical to, the same characters in the adopted standard.
It's quite possible that DEC was represented in the standards committee, and in any case, the committee looked at existing practices as a basis for developing the code.
I had only minimal use of punched cards on a DECsystem-10, and at the time did not consider the details of the code that was used.

Were you typing all that from memory, or is there a reference material online?

I was referring to the specific documents I named. FIPS-14-1 can be found online by a search, and the DEC manuals can be found in the Bitsavers archive.

@EricSmith It would help if you (or another editor) added hyperlinks to your answer, to make it easier to look up the references. (Reference-style Markdown links seem appropriate.)

Added some links.

Did anyone really use punched cards in 1980? I worked at the Census Bureau where punched cards were invented, and they went key-to-disk  in 1976.

Additional notes about Multics:
"The Multics standard card punch codes described in this section are DQ1 identical to the currently proposed ASCII punched card code. The ASCII standard code is not supported by any currently [03/30/67] available punched card equipment; until such support exists it is not a practical standard for Multics work. The Multics standard card punch code described here is based on widely available card handling equipment used with IBM System/360 computers."
http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/Multics/MHP-Saltzer-060508/bookcases/MSPM/bb-3-02.670330.punch-card-codes.pdf

In two out of 5 characters mentioned in John Doty's answer (! and |) Multics diverged from IBM, while the proposed standard follows IBM (as per the document I refer to in the question). It appears that IBM was not internally consistent.

I think the coding represents a means of mapping a combination of punches in the bottom 8 columns to 4 bits and combining that with the pattern of punches in the top 4, so as to recognize 256 distinct punch patterns.  The mapping of 8-bit patterns to characters, however, was chosen to be consistent with existing punch patterns.  For example, digits 0-9 are each represented by a single punch in one of the bottom ten rows, and uppercase letters are mapped to a combination of one of the top three rows plus one of the bottom 9.  Row 9 is repurposed to represent one of the top four bits directly, rather than representing bit pattern 1001 in the bottom four bits, but the bit patterns otherwise resemble EBCDIC more than anything else.

Still, it is unclear how, for example, 0x80 would be represented. Looking at the shape of the available space, there will be no consistent algorithm to convert "ASCII with high bit" to punch patterns.

0x80 would be eight columns from the left, zero from the top.  Character code 0x80 is assigned to the glyph "9".  I think the intention isn't so much that people use this as a code for character data, so much as something analogous to base64 encoding, but for punched cards, and using only one column per encoded byte.  I'm not sure what advantage this would have over a more "binary" oriented approach like having odd columns represent the bits of a byte using rows 1245780- and even columns use 235689+-, an arrangement which would avoid any 2x2 region of punched holes.

Vertically adjacent holes do not matter as much as "lacing" due to horizontally adjacent holes. I know of an encoding that would fill 4 columns with 6 bytes, then left a column unused. Accounting for identifying information and a checksum, there were up to 84 payload bytes per card.

@LeoB. "Vertically adjacent holes do not matter as much" Sorry, but it's the other way around. Vertical holes are most influential to stability. Transport subjects cards to lengthwise shockwaves when handed over between between rolls/conveyors. Note that this may be not an issue for those tiny 200 or even 600 cpm readers, but it definitely is for serious machinery in the 1000..2000 cpm range - even more if those are reader/sorter devices with several meters of multiple transport and point sections. vertical hole combinations waken the lengthwise stability let them wiggle ad get stuck.

@LeoB. (for reference, I got basic training as FSE in 1980 on those and similar OCR devices)

The resemblance to EBCDIC is no accident, since compatibility to encoding used by electromechanical tabulating equipment was essential for both encodings, and  compatibility to EBCDIC extensions of the basic "Hollerith" code was desirable.

@Raffzahn: I would expect that a card wehre half the rows were fully punched while the other were fully blank would be pretty strong, as would one where half the columns were fully punched and the others fully blank.  What I'd think would be worst would be having an orthogonally-connected pattern of punched holes completely surrounding part of the card--something that can only happen if (as in this coding) it's possible for holes to be punched in three vertical columns (as happens for some possible codes in this encoding).

@Raffzahn: Looking at that table, even if one only uses patterns with assigned codes, a sequence of BEL, followed by a sequence of X, followed by another sequence of BEL, would seem like a disaster waiting to happen.  Would you agree?
